# Can we mock a method in service while testing the service itself?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, mybatis

I am working on a project where I am using MyBatis annotations as persistence framework. Therefore, I have to create an interface for the 'mapper' and compose the mapper in the service like :

```
class XYZServiceImpl{

    public XYZMapper getXYZMapper(){
        return SessionUtil.getSqlSession().getMapper(XYZMapper.class)
    }

}
```

Now while unit testing the service with Mockito, I am trying to inject a mock for the mapper. But since I am injecting mock in an instance of XYZService, how can mock a method of the service itself, in this case getXYZMapper() is what I am trying to stub. Although I have got a solution of creating the instance XYZMapper in the service and not call on demand like the above code does something like :

```
  Class XYZServiceImpl{

        XYZMapper mapper;

        public void useXYZMapper(){
            mapper = SessionUtil.getSqlSession().getMapper(XYZMapper.class);
        }

    }
```

But that would bring a lot of code changes (ofcourse I can refactor) but is there a way to achieve without having to make code changes?

Also what would be a 'purist' way to have a mapper instance in the class is it the method 1 that is better than method 2 in terms of performance?

EDIT : Here XYZMapper is an interface. Something like :

```
public interface XYZMapper{
    @Select("SELECT * FROM someclass WHERE id = #{id}")
    public SomeClass getSomeClass(int id);

}
```

EDIT : I am facing a similar situation but with a variance that I have a service that I do want to test like XYZServiceImpl. Now it has a method getXYZDetails() which has a lot of business logic handled within the service. Now if getXYZDetails looks like the following :

```
public XYZDetails getXYZDetails(int id){

  XYZDetails details = new XYZDetails();

  details.set1Details(fetchSet1Details(id));

  //Perform some business logic

  details.set2Details(fetchSet2Details(id));

  if(details.set2Details() != null){
    for(int i = 0; i < details.set2Details().size(); i++){
      flushTheseDetails(i);
    }
  }
  .
  .

}
```

Kindly notice that fetchSet1Details(), fetchSet2Details(), flushTheseDetails are public service, public and private service respectively.

I want to know of a method that can mock/stub these methods while testing getXYZDetails() thus enabling me to

Comment: I'm confused - where is the interface in this? Please use some real code examples - you can't return anything from a `void` method.

Comment: @Duncan : I have provided the info and yes my bad it wasn't a void method. Although I cant understand the downvote but still I would trade learning new information with reputation any day.

Comment: You had a down-vote from me because your question was so unclear it couldn't be answered. Fortunately you improved it and so I removed it.

Comment: @Duncan : Can you kindly respond to my edits? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options you can use.

## Inject dependency

This works only for simple methods like `getXYZMapper` when method only returns external dependency of you object. This may require to create new XYZServiceImpl instances if for example mapper is bound to connection which is opened per request.

## Encapsulate method behavior in object

Another way to achieve similar result is to use a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) or [service locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern)
like this:

```
public class XYZServiceImpl {
    public XYZServiceImpl(XYZMapperFactory mapperFactory) {
        this.mapperFactory = mapperFactory;
    }

    public XYZMapper getXYZMapper() {
        return mapperFactory.getMapper();
    }
}
```

This will allow you easily substitute factory in test with implementation which returns mock mapper.

The similar approach can be used for other methods `fetchSet1Details`, `fetchSet2Details`, `flushTheseDetails` that is moving them to other class or classes. If the method contains complex (and may be loosely related) logic it is a good candidate to be moved in separate class. Think about what these methods do. Usually you can move some essential and unrelated part of them to other class or classes and this makes mocking them much easier.

## Subclass

This is not [recommended](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SubclassToTestAntiPattern) but in legacy code sometimes is very helpful as a temporary solution.

In your test subclass you class under test and override methods you need:

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
   XYZServiceImpl sut = new XYZServiceImpl() {
       public XYZMapper getXYZMapper() {
           return mapperMock;
       }
       public Whatever fetchSet1Details() {
           return whateverYouNeedInTest;
       }
   }

   sut.invokeMethodUnderTest();
}
```

The only thing you may need to do is to change access modifier of private method to package-private or protected so you can override them.

## Spying

This method in also [discouraged](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212493/is-spying-on-tested-class-bad-practice) but you can use mockito spies:

```
XYZServiceImpl realService = new XYZServiceImpl();
XYZServiceImpl spy = Mockito.spy(realService);

when(spy.fetchSet1Details()).thenReturn(whaeveryouneed);
when(spy.getXYZMapper()).thenReturn(mockMapper);

spy.methodUnderTest();
```

Comment: So we can spy the service under test?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the "purist" way of doing this is to accept an `XYZMapper` instance in your constructor and store it in a local field.

In production use, you can pass an e.g. `SQLXYZMapper`, which will interact with your database. In test use, you can pass in a mocked object that you can verify interactions with.

Comment: Okay so I reckon the second method is the real deal of doing things... and does that mean that there is NO way (good or bad or hack) of mocking (or stubbing) a method inside service while testing service itself?

Comment: Yes there is, you could wrap your test object as a [Mockito Spy](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13), but I definitely recommend to approach it the way Duncan described.